# Java 11 issue with jaxb dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I'm attempting an upgrade from the Java 8 version to 11 for a project and I've encountered the following error during build-time after I've manually added the JAXB dependencies:

```
'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} in com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11
```

I'm using Gradle, so I've added the following dependencies:

```
implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"
implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11"
implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"
implementation "javax.activation:activation:1.1.1"
```

I've tried to scour the jaxb pom to search for the place in which the property it's looking for (`tools.jar`) is specified but couldn't find anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use 2.3+ version of `jaxb-...` artifacts. If we check `jaxb-parent-2.3.0.pom` then we see that it doesn't use `<systemPath>${tools.jar}</systemPath>` anymore

Comment: thank you!!! had the same jaxb complaint with java 1, groovy 3.0.8. went with groovy 2.3.6 via sdkman! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `./gradlew dependencies` to find the parent dependency of that jaxb dependency which caused the error.

Then upgrade that dependency to the latest.

For example to fix the error:

```
Errors occurred while build effective model from /home/gayanw/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-osgi/2.2.10/c926a537af564ec047ec6308df1d0d2a03364a86/jaxb-osgi-2.2.10.pom:
    'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${tools.jar} in com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:2.2.10
```

```
$ ./gradlew dependencies
|    \--- io.rest-assured:xml-path:3.0.2 -> 3.3.0
|         +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:2.4.15 -> 2.5.9 (*)
|         +--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.15 -> 2.5.9
|         +--- io.rest-assured:rest-assured-common:3.3.0 (*)
|         +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
|         +--- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1
|         +--- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12 -> 2.3.1
|         |    \--- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0
|         +--- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:2.2.10
```

Here in my case `jaxb-osgi` is introduced by `io.rest-assured:xml-path`. So upgrading that dependency should fix it.

```
testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:xml-path:4.2.0'
```

Comment: I'm using `io.rest-assured:xml-path:3.3.0` als part of `spring-boot-starter-web -> 2.3.3.RELEASE` and I still receive this error

Comment: I am using rest-assured and this fixed it instantly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

have same issue now ,   i just upgrade everthing in my gradle

```
implementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.3.2'
implementation 'io.rest-assured:json-path:4.3.2'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-osgi', version: '2.3.2'
```

the error disappear
EDIT : for my project, if i used more updated version of jaxb-osgi , it wouldnt work (the error disappear but the test stop to run )

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding

```
ext['rest-assured.version'] = '4.3.1'
```

to your build.gradle file will override the version which ships with your version of spring-cloud, and all the versions of `io.rest-assured:**` jars downloaded will have the same number